# Java equivalent of Python "join" method for array?

Tags: java

How can I do this Python trick in Java?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print ' '.join(l)
1 2 3 4 5
```

This doesn't apply to Strings only. I am using generics and need to print any kind of value in the Array.

Comment: If you can't figure out the duplicate link, drop a comment and someone will repoen the question.

Comment: This doesn't apply to Strings only. I am using generics and need to print any kind of value in the Array.

Comment: Here's the thing, the final join step requires concatening everything with space, which is a string.  So I would say that you should first convert the array elements to string before joining.

Comment: Ah, right. And that would hold true even if I joined with an empty string. Thanks.